# C# Override Compare method of IComparer Interface

Tags: c#, return-value, asterisk, icomparer

I have a class which overwrites the Compare method of IComarer class.
Can you please explain me the code portion "return v1v2.CompareTo(v2v1)*  -1;"?
What * is representing here?Why we are subtracting the value by 1?

```
public class ValueComparator : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    public int Compare(Object lhs, object rhs)
    {
        string v1 = lhs.ToString();
        string v2 = rhs.ToString();
        string v1v2 = v1 + v2;
        string v2v1 = v2 + v1;
        return v1v2.CompareTo(v2v1)*  -1;

    }
}
```

Comment: `*` is not substraction, it's multiplication.  Not sure why it's doing that.  It could have been written as `v2v1.CompareTo(v1v2)` instead, without the multiplication.

Comment: Its not a subtraction, its inverting the value.

Comment: Thanks Ron, Depending on the value of v1v2 and v2v1 v1v2.CompareTo(v2v1)  may return >0, 0 OR <0. But after that I am not getting what the rest code portion is doing. The code is written to give the highest possible value of a given integer array 
            int[] nums ={ 50, 5, 56 };
            Array.Sort(nums, new ValueComparator());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is essentially reversing the comparison.  Since Compare returns -1 (less than), 0 (equal), or 1 (greater), by multiplying it by -1, it reverses the results -1 becomes 1, 0 remains 0, and 1 becomes -1.

As sstan mentioned, it probably should have written as `v2v1.CompareTo(v1v2)` instead.

Comment: The bit about returning -1 or 1 is not entirely accurate. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) merely requires a negative or a positive value, not necessarily -1 or 1.

Comment: Small qualm, it is not `-1`, `0`, `1` it is `< 0`, `0`, and `> 0` it is perfectly legal for the comparer to return `-275`, `0`, `600`. This looser restriction is beneficial because you can implement `int Compare(int a, int b) { return a - b; }` as simple subtractions instead of needing to involve boolean logic.

Comment: Importantly, this implementation is broken because `int.MinValue * -1` will still be `int.MinValue`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: "because you can implement `int Compare(int a, int b) { return a - b; }`" - well, you *should* not, unless you want to provoke overflows, but for smaller range types than `int`, that's a valid implementation for `Compare`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true, I thought about that but did not write it down. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks everyone , I got my answer, This is basically to sort an arry such that is gives highest possible number "int[] nums ={ 50, 5, 56 }; Array.Sort(nums, new ValueComparator());" While comparing they are reversing the value... for example 505 is less that 550 so here 5 is bigger than 50 for this particular case!!!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  You are all of course correct, and should help anyone else who reads this in the future.